# Silverlight Spy, FireBug type tool for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, silverlight, debugging, firebug

Is there a debugging tool for Flex that functions like Silverlight spy or FireBug?

Comment: you can use firebug to see flex requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/). It has an AIR app that acts like firebug, let you inspect/change variables, call public methods at runtime, etc. It is not Flex only, instead, you can use it in any as3 project.

[reflexutil](http://code.google.com/p/reflexutil/) is for flex. But I haven't used it.

Also, I found [the list of helpful Flex or Flash debug tools](http://ntt.cc/2008/03/29/the-list-of-helpful-flex-or-flash-debug-tools.html).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [flexbug](http://code.google.com/p/flexbug/), its built on [fxspy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/).  I'm sure how well supported it is, but its open source so if you don't like something... change it :)

For remote objects, http services, web services etc.  I like [charles.](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)